# How to create Application name in multiple languages for Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

say, I have created a WP7 app using the default language in English. The application name that will show in the Application List is English. Now, If I want to change this english-Application name to other languages such as japanese, Chinese,Korean. what I need to do? would appreciate your help with some samples or links of references or tutorial on this subject. It is ok to use part english and part other language to create application name?

Comment: Just make sure the names reflect the marketplace names. I had users that found it odd if the name at installation, wasn't the same as the name in the application-list after the installation.

Answer (score 2):

This is described on [MSDN here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967550%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) It's a bit convoluted but it does work.

Comment: This content is no longer available at this location.

Answer (score 1):

While Paul Annett's answer represents the official recommendations, it also requires that you have the tools for C++ development (which the Windows Phone tools do not).

Patrick's Blog (I've been unable to find a surname) has posted a tool called [WP7 Localizer](http://patrickgetzmann.wordpress.com/wp7-localize/) that generates the localized dlls without having the C++ tools installed